# Android: Store in preferences or SQLite

Tags: android

I have to store informations about the user, should I user SQL lite or preferences?

If I use SQLlite, will the data dissaper when the app is shut down or telefon? 
Cause I need them to be saved whenever he opens the app.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use SQLlite, will the data dissaper when the app is shut down or telefon?

No, the data will remain there until the user uninstalls your app or factory resets the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is flat/denormalized and in key/value pair format, I would recommend using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

See this article for more information:
[Android Developers - Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: what does it my by if data is flat denormalized?